# Form alignment issue firefox, ie 9 & 8

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this form on this page: http://powellgroupconstruction.com/contact-us/ but in firefox, ie 9 & 8 the form button does align to the end of the textbox (chrome does it perfectly)...how would i fix that?

```
<p style="float:left; width:440px;"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap message"><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" style="
    height: 115px;
">Questions/Comments</textarea></span> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://powellgroupconstruction.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;"></p>

input.wpcf7-submit {
float: right;
border-radius: 5px !important;
background-color: #FFF !important;
color: #000 !important;
background-image: none !important;
border: 0 !important;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` is wider than the `p` element – it looks like you have given the `textarea` no `width` at all, so that its width simply relies on its `cols` …

Give it a `width` of `100%` and set `box-sizing` to `border-box` (still needs to be prefixed `-moz-box-sizing` for Firefox), then it should fit into the available width.

Comment: looks good in chrome, firefox, safari, iphone & ipad. But the button is still a bit to right in IE 11, 10, 9, 8, 7 & 6